# Runtime error when using yolov5-inference package

Tags: python, yolov5

I am trying to use yolov5-inference package for yolov5 object detection. But it gives an runtime error.

This is the code for object detection

```
from yolov5_inference.infer import DetectObject
import cv2
import numpy as np

class_name = {0: 'head', 1: 'helmet', 2: 'person'}
model = DetectObject(weights='best.pt', classes=class_name)
img_path = 'bus.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
print(img.shape)
rs = model.detect(img)
print(rs)
```

This is the error.

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (60) must match the size of tensor b (84) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

Has anyone came across this problem?

Comment: best.pt is the model that I trained using the 'https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5' repository.